# CSS Image escaping parent

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to learn responsive design so i'm working off a tutorial. my banner image when the window size shrinks escapes the banner div and the right side doesn't resize correctly. i've narrowed it down to some styling that is being applied to the banner div but i cannot figure it out for the life of me. what part of my coding would allow it to do so?

live version can be seen here:
http://ctxdesigns.net/nelson/

According to chrome, this is what's being applied to #banner

```
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto;
border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: 'Times New Roman';
font-size: 16px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 500px;
line-height: normal;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 9.796875px;
padding-left: 9.796875px;
padding-right: 9.796875px;
padding-top: 9.796875px;
vertical-align: baseline;
width: 980px;
```

Comment: Are you referring to the white border on the right of the banner going off the edge of the screen? If so, it is related to the fact that the banner's padding increases its total width beyond `980px`.

Comment: What do you mean by escapes the banner div?  Do you mean that little bit of white "border" that goes off the edge of the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding 1% padding to 100% div which is the issue(needs to be 98% since you are adding 1% on left and right):

Do this:

```
#banner {
background: white;
display: block;
float: left;
padding: 1%;
height: auto;
width: 98%;
}
```

You will see that it will be accurate.

If you need to keep banner at 100% then add an inner div to have the padding..

Comment: The `width` is actually specified as `980px`. See CSS in the question.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I'm not sure where that CSS in the question came from... I don't see it in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The default CSS Box model defines sizing like this:

[image: Box model diagram]

The padding, border, and margin are added *on top of* the width. So, the final width ends up like `width = width + padding + border`, and then the margin is added on that.

So when you set

```
#banner {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
}
```

The final width ends up being 102% (100% + 1% + 1%).

Some may think this is unintuitive and doesnt make sense. Thankfully, you can use the 
[`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) propety to fix that. By setting it to `border-box`, you will get the sizing you expect. It pushes the padding and border inwards, rather than outwards. So, if you have

```
#banner {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You will get an element that is 100% wide, but has 1% of padding on the inside.

`box-sizing` has fairly good browser support, as long as you don't need to target IE 7 and below.

If you're going to use box-sizing, [many would advocate](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) setting a global selector to apply `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements.

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```